# Do I need a separate database to store user input data for security reason

Tags: database, rest, amazon-web-services, security, architecture

We are building a web application and plan to run it on AWS. Created a RDS instance with MySQL. The proposed architecture is as follows:
[image]
Data is being uploaded from company data mart to `Core DB` in RDS. On the other side, user is sending data through our Rest API to post data. This user input data will be saved in a separate DB within the same RDS, as one of our architects suggested. The data will then be periodically copied to a table inside `Core DB`. We will have a rule engine running based `Core DB`. Whenever an exception is detected, notification will be sent to customers.

The overall structure seems fine. One thing I would change though is instead of having two separate DBs, we can just have one DB and have user input data in a table in the same Database. The logic behind separate DBs, according to our architect, is for security concerns. Since Core DB will have data from our company, it is better to be on its own. So the http requests from clients will only affect the user input DB.

While it makes sense, I am not sure it is really necessary. First all the user input is authenticated. Secondly the web api provides another protection layer against database since it only allows certain requests, which in this case couple of endpoints for post request. Besides if someone can somehow still hack into the `User Input DB` in RDS, since the it resides on the same RDS instance plus there is data transfer between DBs, it is not impossible they can't get to `Core`.

That said, do we really need separate DBs? And if this is the way to go, what is best way to sync from `User Input DB` to a `User Input TB` in `Core DB`?

Comment: A separate database is not fundamentally/automatically/magically more secure in any way.  With db user permissions, it is possible to limit the access that the REST server has to the data, and db-level permissions (as opposed to table-level, which is what you would need otherwise) might make the delineation cleaner and less error-prone... but it's not really clear whether there's enough information here to give an authoritative answer.  You definitely should restrict internal the credentials used by the REST API so that unintentional access is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of security reason, separating the db are not magically make it true. My suggestion :

1. Restrict the API layer, such as only have write access ( just in case to avoiding accidentally deleting data)
2. For credentials data, don't put it on source code, you can put it as environment variables, example on [ElasticBeanstalk Environment Variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-during.html)
3. For RDS itself, put it under [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/)

In term of synchronizing data if you have to go with 2 db.

1. if your two database are exactly same on the schema, you can use db replication capability (such as mysql replication)
2. if not, you can send it to message broker service (SQS) then create a worker to pulling it then save it to target database
3. or you can use another service such as [datapipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/)